# how to read sas file in chunks in python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, sas

I've got code as follows:

```
asm_data=[]
asm=pd.read_sas('path_to_my_file',encoding='utf-8',chunksize=10000,iterator=True)
for chunk in asm:
    asm_data.append(asm)
```

the output is asm_data as list of sas7bdatreader files.
How can I concat all this files in one dataframe. pd.concat doesn't work since this are sas files

Answer (score 1):

found it :)

```
asm_data=[]
asm=pd.read_sas('path_to_my_file',encoding='utf-8',chunksize=10000,iterator=True)

for chunk in asm:
    asm_data.append(chunk)
asm_data_df=pd.concat(asm_data)
```

The point was append 'chunk' as above. My mistake.